# Getting Anchor Points of an Vectorized Image in Illustrator

Tags: flash, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have a cartoon image which is vectorized in illustrator. All the anchor points are put by illustrator. What I want to get is the coordinates of all those anchor points and put it into a file. I tried to read anchor point coordinates over SVG file , however, even though data contains x coordinate, I could not find any related thing about Y coordinate of an anchor point. How can I solve this problem?

The sample data of SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M113.2,253.7c99.9,0,199.8,0,299.7,0c0,100.5,0,201.1,0,301.6
    c-100.5,0-201.1,0-301.6,0c0-98.6,0-197.2,0-295.8C111.1,256.7,110.9,254,113.2,253.7z M257.2,310.1c0.6,3.8-2.6,3.9-3.9,5.8
    c7.1,0,14.3,0,21.4,0c6,2.4,13.8,3,21.4,3.9c6.1,2.3,9.6,7.3,17.5,7.8c-2.4-10-16.8-7.8-25.3-11.7c-9.7-0.7-19.8-0.9-27.2-3.9
    c3-9.2,21.2,2.1,21.4-5.8c-18.2-0.6-39.9,2.3-50.6-5.8c0-5.2,0-10.4,0-15.6c2.4-0.8,4-2.5,3.9-5.8c9.4-10.6,28.7-10.9,46.7-11.7
    c13.5-0.6-3-1.9-7.8-1.9c-22.5,0-31.8,3.1-44.8,13.6c0.5,5.7-4.4,6-3.9,11.7C226.1,307.5,244.7,305.8,257.2,310.1z M296.1,269.2
    c1.8-4.8-11.1-0.6-3.9,0C295.4,269.1,300.7,272.5,296.1,269.2z M337,360.7c-3.2,6.5-4,15.4-9.7,19.5c-5.2-6.5-9.7-13.7-23.4-11.7
    c0.3-6.8-0.5-12.5-3.9-15.6c0.9-4.9-3.8-14.1-5.8-9.7c5.8,6,5.2,24,5.8,29.2c1.4-4.4,10.9-0.8,15.6-1.9c1.2,5.3,8.1,4.8,7.8,11.7
    c0.7,16.9-10.6,21.9-25.3,23.4c-4.3-2.9-14.5,0.2-15.6-5.8c-17.3,2.6-31.1-3.9-42.8-11.7c-7.1-4.7-16.7-9.6-15.6-19.5
    c6.4,4,15,5.8,23.4,7.8c-1.7-8.1-13.7-5.8-19.5-9.7c-2.9-4.9-6.9-8.7-7.8-15.6c0.9-8.1,4.6-13.6,11.7-15.6c5.5,1,10.1,2.9,15.6,3.9
    c0.8,7,2.6,13,5.8,17.5c0.4-1.5,0.1-3.8,1.9-3.9c5.4,3.1,5.4-8.4,1.9-7.8c-1.9,2-3.8,3.9-5.8,5.8c-1.9-5.8-0.5-11.8-1.9-13.6
    c0.6,4-5.6-0.4-5.8-1.9c-0.6-5.1,7.5-1.5,5.8-7.8c-10.9-1.2-10.1,3.5-11.7,7.8c0-3.2-5.4-1.1-5.8-3.9c-0.6-9.7,7.7-10.4,11.7-15.6
    c-9.3,1.4-17.7,8.6-13.6,17.5c-8,1.8-13.5,6-15.6,13.6c-0.5,12.2,5.8,17.6,5.8,29.2c7.1,7.2,14.4,14.2,23.4,19.5
    c-17,0.1-30.4-3.3-48.6-1.9c-8.2,4.2-13.7,10.9-23.4,13.6c-10.5-1.2-13.9-9.4-27.2-7.8c-4,3.1-4.5,9.8-3.9,17.5
    c6.3,4.7,12.2,9.8,25.3,7.8c5.6,1.5,5,9.2,13.6,7.8c0.1,10.3,9.4,11.3,19.5,11.7c1.9-2.6,5.2-3.9,7.8-5.8c2.1-7.3-4.8-5.5-3.9-11.7
    c8.5,2,6.4-6.6,13.6-5.8c9.1,0,18.2,0,27.2,0c-2.4,4.1-5.4,7.6-7.8,11.7c-4.9-4.7-9.5,1.9-13.6,3.9c-3,8.9,1.5,8.2,1.9,17.5
    c-38.3-3.9-38,50.7-27.2,77.8c-4-1.2-12.8,2.4-13.6-1.9c4.8,0.3,9.4,0.4,9.7-3.9c-7.9,0.6-13.5,3.3-21.4,3.9
    c2.2,12.1,19.4,9.1,29.2,13.6c13.2-1.1,30.8,2.3,40.9-1.9c16,12.3,49,5.1,50.6-15.6c-4.4-9.3-12.3-14.9-21.4-19.5
    c19.6-15.4,31.2-47.1,23.4-83.7c18.8,0,32.6-5,52.5-3.9c3.7,0.8,3.5,5.6,9.7,3.9c4.9-2.2,9.5-4.8,13.6-7.8
    c5.6,0.9,6.1,6.9,13.6,5.8c1.7-4.1,5.9-5.8,5.8-11.7c-0.8-8.2-9.1-9.1-15.6-11.7c4.1-10.1,8.1-20.5,7.8-35
    c-3.9-4.5-6.5-10.4-13.6-11.7c-7.1,2.6-12,7.4-19.5,9.7c-4.7,10.9-9.7,21.4-13.6,33.1c-2.8-1.1-10.1,2.3-9.7-1.9
    c11.4-10,16.4-26.4,17.5-46.7c-2.4-12.5-5.4-24.4-9.7-35c-4.4-10.5-14-15.8-17.5-27.2c-6.1,0.9-5.1-5.2-9.7-5.8
    c-0.4-2.2-2.2-3-3.9-3.9c0.2-2.4-2.8-1.2,0,0C321.4,294.5,340.5,316.3,337,360.7z M257.2,329.6c5.5-2.2,10.1-2.2,15.6,0
    C272.6,314.3,251.1,333.4,257.2,329.6z M292.2,331.5c1.2,4-3.7,10.7,0,5.8c4.2-1.2,1.8-12,0-13.6c-5.9-0.1-9.9,1.8-11.7,5.8
    C285.5,328.1,289.5,326.7,292.2,331.5z M261.1,333.4c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9C259.7,335.9,262.1,334.5,261.1,333.4z M265,335.4
    C273.5,345.5,261.4,329.2,265,335.4L265,335.4z M286.4,343.2c0.7-6-6.7-13.9-11.7-7.8C284,332.6,282.2,340.9,286.4,343.2z
     M255.3,335.4c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9C253.8,337.9,256.3,336.4,255.3,335.4z M272.8,335.4c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9
    C271.4,337.9,273.8,336.4,272.8,335.4z M284.4,345.1c-1.3-1.6-1.8,3.6-1.9,3.9C279.7,354.6,286,347.1,284.4,345.1z M272.8,358.7
    c4-1.5,9.8-9.6,1.9-11.7c-0.4,2.2-2.2,3-3.9,3.9C273.3,355.8,269.8,357.1,272.8,358.7z M265,358.7c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9
    C263.6,361.2,266,359.8,265,358.7z M266.9,382.1c-2.1-0.1-4.9,0.9-1.9,1.9c5.7-1.7,6-1.7,11.7,0c-0.2-5-2.8-7.5-7.8-7.8
    C268.6,378.5,269.2,381.8,266.9,382.1z M247.5,386c4.5,0,9.1,0,13.6,0c-0.8-4.4-9.6-0.8-13.6-1.9c-0.3-3.6-6.6-1.2-7.8-3.9
    c-0.8-2.3-9.5-2.3-3.9,0C238.8,383,244.9,382.7,247.5,386z M311.7,387.9c5.5-0.4,4.9,7.7,7.8,0c-1.5-0.4-3.8-0.1-3.9-1.9
    c-5.2,0-10.4,0-15.6,0c-2.9,0-15.9-0.7-9.7,1.9c5.9-0.1,12.8-1.1,11.7,5.8c-4.9,7.8-16-7-15.6,1.9
    C298.2,400.6,306.2,394.7,311.7,387.9z M377.8,531.9c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9C376.4,534.4,378.9,532.9,377.8,531.9z M370.1,535.8
    c0-1.1-1.6-2.2-1.9,0C368.1,536.9,369.7,538,370.1,535.8z M399.3,533.9c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9
    C397.8,536.4,400.3,534.9,399.3,533.9z M383.7,539.7c0.1-2.1-0.9-4.9-1.9-1.9C381.7,539.8,382.7,542.7,383.7,539.7z M389.5,535.8
    c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9C388.1,538.3,390.5,536.8,389.5,535.8z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M259.1,335.4c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C262.1,334.5,259.7,335.9,259.1,335.4z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M253.3,337.3c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C256.3,336.4,253.8,337.9,253.3,337.3z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M270.8,337.3c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C273.8,336.4,271.4,337.9,270.8,337.3z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M263,360.7c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C266,359.8,263.6,361.2,263,360.7z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M183.3,421c10.5,2.1-7,14.3-5.8,1.9
    C180.2,423.1,182.9,423.3,183.3,421z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M230,432.7c4.9,3.1-1.3,11.5-5.8,11.7
    C222.4,436.8,228.9,437.4,230,432.7z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M251.4,448.3c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C254.3,447.3,251.9,448.8,251.4,448.3z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M255.3,450.2c0.1-1.9,2.4-1.5,3.9-1.9C259.1,450.2,256.8,449.8,255.3,450.2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M261.1,452.2c0.3-2.3,3.5-1.6,5.8-1.9C266.6,452.5,263.4,451.8,261.1,452.2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M280.5,452.2c0.3-2.3,3.5-1.6,5.8-1.9C286.1,452.5,282.8,451.8,280.5,452.2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M253.3,479.4c-0.8,6.6-12.7,4.5-9.7-3.9
    C247.3,476.3,247.1,481.1,253.3,479.4z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M286.4,530c-1.3,15.6-25.9,16-40.9,11.7
    c4.1-7.1,8.8-17.3,1.9-25.3c8-2.4,16.1-4.7,23.4-7.8C276.9,514.8,286.5,517.6,286.4,530z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M375.9,533.9c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C378.9,532.9,376.4,534.4,375.9,533.9z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M368.1,535.8c0.4-2.2,2-1.1,1.9,0C369.7,538,368.1,536.9,368.1,535.8z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M397.3,535.8c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C400.3,534.9,397.8,536.4,397.3,535.8z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M381.7,537.8c1-3,2-0.1,1.9,1.9C382.7,542.7,381.7,539.8,381.7,537.8z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M387.6,537.8c-1-1,1.4-2.5,1.9-1.9C390.5,536.8,388.1,538.3,387.6,537.8z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M226.1,290.6c-0.5-5.7,4.4-6,3.9-11.7c13-10.5,22.3-13.6,44.8-13.6
    c4.8,0,21.3,1.4,7.8,1.9c-18,0.8-37.3,1.1-46.7,11.7c0.1,3.3-1.4,5-3.9,5.8c0,5.2,0,10.4,0,15.6c10.7,8.1,32.4,5.3,50.6,5.8
    c-0.2,7.9-18.5-3.3-21.4,5.8c7.4,3,17.5,3.2,27.2,3.9c8.5,3.9,22.9,1.7,25.3,11.7c-8-0.5-11.4-5.5-17.5-7.8
    c-7.6-0.9-15.4-1.5-21.4-3.9c-7.1,0-14.3,0-21.4,0c1.3-2,4.5-2,3.9-5.8C244.7,305.8,226.1,307.5,226.1,290.6z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M292.2,269.2c-7.2-0.6,5.7-4.8,3.9,0C300.7,272.5,295.4,269.1,292.2,269.2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M302,273.1C299.1,271.9,302.2,270.8,302,273.1c1.7,0.9,3.5,1.7,3.9,3.9
    c4.6,0.6,3.6,6.8,9.7,5.8c3.5,11.4,13.1,16.7,17.5,27.2c4.3,10.6,7.3,22.5,9.7,35c-1.1,20.3-6.1,36.7-17.5,46.7
    c-0.3,4.2,6.9,0.9,9.7,1.9c3.9-11.7,9-22.2,13.6-33.1c7.4-2.3,12.3-7.1,19.5-9.7c7.2,1.3,9.7,7.2,13.6,11.7
    c0.3,14.6-3.7,24.9-7.8,35c6.5,2.6,14.7,3.4,15.6,11.7c0.1,5.9-4.1,7.6-5.8,11.7c-7.5,1-8-5-13.6-5.8c-4.1,3-8.7,5.6-13.6,7.8
    c-6.2,1.7-6-3.1-9.7-3.9c-20-1.2-33.7,3.9-52.5,3.9c7.9,36.6-3.8,68.3-23.4,83.7c9.1,4.5,17,10.2,21.4,19.5
    c-1.6,20.7-34.5,27.9-50.6,15.6c-10,4.2-27.7,0.9-40.9,1.9c-9.8-4.5-27-1.5-29.2-13.6c7.9-0.6,13.5-3.3,21.4-3.9
    c-0.3,4.3-4.9,4.2-9.7,3.9c0.8,4.4,9.6,0.8,13.6,1.9c-10.7-27.1-11.1-81.7,27.2-77.8c-0.4-9.3-5-8.6-1.9-17.5
    c4.1-1.9,8.7-8.6,13.6-3.9c2.4-4.1,5.4-7.6,7.8-11.7c-9.1,0-18.2,0-27.2,0c-7.2-0.7-5.1,7.9-13.6,5.8c-0.9,6.1,6,4.4,3.9,11.7
    c-2.6,1.9-5.9,3.2-7.8,5.8c-10-0.3-19.4-1.4-19.5-11.7c-8.6,1.4-8-6.3-13.6-7.8c-13.1,2-19-3-25.3-7.8c-0.6-7.8-0.1-14.4,3.9-17.5
    c13.3-1.6,16.8,6.6,27.2,7.8c9.6-2.7,15.2-9.5,23.4-13.6c18.3-1.4,31.7,2.1,48.6,1.9c-9-5.3-16.3-12.2-23.4-19.5
    c0-11.6-6.3-17-5.8-29.2c2.1-7.7,7.6-11.8,15.6-13.6c-4.1-8.9,4.3-16.2,13.6-17.5c-3.9,5.2-12.2,5.9-11.7,15.6
    c0.4,2.8,5.8,0.7,5.8,3.9c1.6-4.3,0.7-9,11.7-7.8c1.7,6.3-6.4,2.7-5.8,7.8c0.2,1.5,6.4,5.9,5.8,1.9c1.4,1.8,0.1,7.8,1.9,13.6
    c2-1.9,3.9-3.8,5.8-5.8c3.4-0.6,3.5,10.9-1.9,7.8c-1.9,0.1-1.5,2.4-1.9,3.9c-3.3-4.5-5.1-10.5-5.8-17.5c-5.5-1-10.1-2.9-15.6-3.9
    c-7.1,2-10.7,7.4-11.7,15.6c0.9,6.9,4.9,10.7,7.8,15.6c5.8,4,17.8,1.7,19.5,9.7c-8.4-2-16.9-3.8-23.4-7.8
    c-1.2,9.8,8.5,14.8,15.6,19.5c11.7,7.7,25.5,14.3,42.8,11.7c1.1,6.1,11.3,3,15.6,5.8c14.7-1.5,26-6.4,25.3-23.4
    c0.3-6.8-6.6-6.4-7.8-11.7c-4.7,1.2-14.1-2.4-15.6,1.9c-0.6-5.2-0.1-23.2-5.8-29.2c2-4.3,6.7,4.8,5.8,9.7c3.4,3.1,4.2,8.8,3.9,15.6
    c13.7-2,18.2,5.2,23.4,11.7c5.7-4,6.5-12.9,9.7-19.5C340.5,316.3,321.4,294.5,302,273.1z M366.2,352.9
    c-11.7,6.5-12.5,23.8-21.4,33.1c1.3-9.8,11.2-21.1,9.7-27.2c-3.6,5.4-8.7,9.5-9.7,17.5c-4.8,4.5-5,16.6-5.8,19.5
    c-4.5,0-9.1,0-13.6,0c-6.3,5.3-13.4,9.9-23.4,11.7c-33.9-5-67-10.9-105.1-11.7c-7.9,3.7-11.6,11.8-21.4,13.6
    c-13.8,1.4-21.9-12.1-31.1-3.9c-2.1,9.9,5.8,9.8,7.8,15.6c15,3.6,32.8-7.3,40.9,1.9c-4.2,3.6-9.9,5.7-7.8,15.6
    c3.4,5.1,14.1,5.1,17.5,0c2.1-7.3-4.8-5.5-3.9-11.7c4.8,0.3,6-3.1,9.7-3.9c-0.6-4.5-2.3-8-3.9-11.7c9.8,10.9,38,3.5,52.5,9.7
    c-1.9,2-3.8,3.9-5.8,5.8c-3.1-0.2-1.5-5-5.8-3.9c-1.1,4.8-7.5,4.1-5.8,11.7c-7.9,3.1-10.2,11.8-11.7,21.4
    c11.8,0.6,13.8,10.9,17.5,19.5c8,1,15.3,2.8,23.4,3.9c3.4-0.7,12-5.9,13.6-1.9c-5.7-0.5-6.7,3.7-9.7,5.8c1.2-4.2-16.9-1.8-9.7,0
    c2.9,0.3,7.2-0.7,7.8,1.9c-13.5-0.8-16.6-2.4-23.4,1.9c-2.7-4.5-9.7-4.6-11.7-9.7c3.5,0.2,4.6-1.9,3.9-5.8
    c-3.8-10.8-21.3-15-35-9.7c-14.2,10.4-14.3,44.7-7.8,64.2c8.6,8.9,18.9,16.1,38.9,13.6c4.6-4.5,11.1-7.1,11.7-15.6
    c1.2-14.2-19.9-16.4-17.5-25.3c8.3,5.4,13.3,13.9,29.2,11.7c17.6-12.9,34-27,33.1-58.4c0-2.6-3.4-1.8-3.9-3.9
    c2.4-0.2,4.6-0.6,3.9-3.9c3.5-14-6.4-24.6-1.9-33.1c3.1,1.4-0.4,9.5,5.8,7.8c17.1,2.5,33.9-5.7,48.6-3.9c4.3,0.5,6.5,4.9,11.7,3.9
    c9.4-5.4,16.4-6.3,27.2-1.9c3-6.1,1.2-10.9-1.9-15.6c-7.3-1.5-9.3,2.4-15.6,1.9c-2.4-21.1,20.8-26.5,9.7-44.8
    c-6.3-1.1-9.8,0.6-11.7,3.9C361.7,356.8,377,354.9,366.2,352.9z M177.4,423c-1.1,12.4,16.3,0.1,5.8-1.9
    C182.9,423.3,180.2,423.1,177.4,423z M173.5,426.9C182,437,170,420.6,173.5,426.9L173.5,426.9z M243.6,475.5
    c-3,8.4,8.9,10.5,9.7,3.9C247.1,481.1,247.3,476.3,243.6,475.5z M224.1,444.4c4.5-0.2,10.7-8.6,5.8-11.7
    C228.9,437.4,222.4,436.8,224.1,444.4z M270.8,508.6c-7.3,3.1-15.3,5.4-23.4,7.8c6.9,8,2.2,18.2-1.9,25.3c15,4.3,39.6,4,40.9-11.7
    C286.5,517.6,276.9,514.8,270.8,508.6z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M272.8,329.6c-5.5-2.2-10.1-2.2-15.6,0C251.1,333.4,272.6,314.3,272.8,329.6z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M280.5,329.6c1.8-4.1,5.7-5.9,11.7-5.8c1.8,1.6,4.2,12.4,0,13.6
    c-3.7,4.9,1.2-1.9,0-5.8C289.5,326.7,285.5,328.1,280.5,329.6z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M265,335.4C261.4,329.2,273.5,345.5,265,335.4L265,335.4z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M274.7,335.4c5-6.1,12.4,1.7,11.7,7.8C282.2,340.9,284,332.6,274.7,335.4z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M282.5,349c0.2-0.3,0.7-5.5,1.9-3.9C286,347.1,279.7,354.6,282.5,349z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M270.8,351c1.7-0.9,3.5-1.7,3.9-3.9c7.8,2.1,2,10.2-1.9,11.7
    C269.8,357.1,273.3,355.8,270.8,351z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M364.2,362.6c1.9-3.3,5.4-5,11.7-3.9
    c11.1,18.2-12.2,23.7-9.7,44.8c6.3,0.4,8.2-3.4,15.6-1.9c3.2,4.7,5,9.5,1.9,15.6c-10.8-4.4-17.8-3.4-27.2,1.9
    c-5.2,1-7.4-3.4-11.7-3.9c-14.7-1.8-31.6,6.4-48.6,3.9c-6.3,1.7-2.7-6.3-5.8-7.8c-4.5,8.4,5.5,19.1,1.9,33.1
    c0.7,3.3-1.5,3.7-3.9,3.9c0.5,2.1,3.9,1.3,3.9,3.9c0.9,31.4-15.5,45.5-33.1,58.4c-15.9,2.3-20.9-6.3-29.2-11.7
    c-2.3,8.9,18.7,11.1,17.5,25.3c-0.6,8.5-7,11.1-11.7,15.6c-20,2.5-30.3-4.7-38.9-13.6c-6.5-19.6-6.4-53.8,7.8-64.2
    c13.7-5.3,31.3-1,35,9.7c0.7,3.9-0.4,6.1-3.9,5.8c2,5.2,9,5.3,11.7,9.7c6.8-4.4,9.9-2.7,23.4-1.9c-0.6-2.6-4.9-1.6-7.8-1.9
    c-7.1-1.8,10.9-4.2,9.7,0c3-2.2,4.1-6.3,9.7-5.8c-1.6-3.9-10.3,1.2-13.6,1.9c-8-1-15.3-2.8-23.4-3.9c-3.7-8.6-5.7-18.9-17.5-19.5
    c1.4-9.6,3.8-18.3,11.7-21.4c-1.7-7.5,4.8-6.9,5.8-11.7c4.3-1.1,2.8,3.7,5.8,3.9c2-1.9,3.9-3.8,5.8-5.8
    c-14.5-6.2-42.7,1.2-52.5-9.7c1.6,3.6,3.3,7.1,3.9,11.7c-3.7,0.8-4.9,4.2-9.7,3.9c-0.9,6.1,6,4.4,3.9,11.7
    c-3.4,5.1-14.1,5.1-17.5,0c-2.1-9.9,3.6-12,7.8-15.6c-8.1-9.3-25.9,1.7-40.9-1.9c-2-5.8-9.9-5.7-7.8-15.6
    c9.2-8.2,17.3,5.3,31.1,3.9c9.9-1.8,13.5-9.9,21.4-13.6c38.1,0.8,71.2,6.7,105.1,11.7c9.9-1.8,17-6.3,23.4-11.7c4.5,0,9.1,0,13.6,0
    c0.9-2.9,1-15,5.8-19.5c1.1-8,6.1-12.1,9.7-17.5c1.5,6.1-8.4,17.5-9.7,27.2c8.9-9.2,9.7-26.6,21.4-33.1
    C377,354.9,361.7,356.8,364.2,362.6z M231.9,504.7c-7.3,4-11.4-9.1-11.7,0C225.5,504.7,229.3,512.9,231.9,504.7z M356.4,387.9
    c-0.2-8.7,11.6-15.6,5.8-23.4C362.8,373.6,351.4,380.8,356.4,387.9z M245.5,444.4c2.1,0.8,4.7,2.3,1.9,0c0-3.3-10.6-9.9-5.8-5.8
    C242.1,441.3,244.8,441.8,245.5,444.4z M253.3,446.3c-0.5-0.5-3,0.9-1.9,1.9C251.9,448.8,254.3,447.3,253.3,446.3z M259.1,448.3
    c-1.5,0.4-3.8,0.1-3.9,1.9C256.8,449.8,259.1,450.2,259.1,448.3z M266.9,450.2c-2.3,0.3-5.5-0.3-5.8,1.9
    C263.4,451.8,266.6,452.5,266.9,450.2z M286.4,450.2c-2.3,0.3-5.5-0.3-5.8,1.9C282.8,451.8,286.1,452.5,286.4,450.2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M220.2,504.7c0.3-9.1,4.4,4,11.7,0C229.3,512.9,225.5,504.7,220.2,504.7z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M362.3,364.6c5.7,7.8-6,14.7-5.8,23.4C351.4,380.8,362.8,373.6,362.3,364.6z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M268.9,376.3c5,0.2,7.5,2.8,7.8,7.8c-5.7-1.7-6-1.7-11.7,0c-3-1-0.1-2,1.9-1.9
    C269.2,381.8,268.6,378.5,268.9,376.3z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M235.8,380.2c-5.6-2.3,3.1-2.3,3.9,0c1.2,2.7,7.5,0.3,7.8,3.9
    c4,1.2,12.8-2.4,13.6,1.9c-4.5,0-9.1,0-13.6,0C244.9,382.7,238.8,383,235.8,380.2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M286.4,395.7c-0.4-8.9,10.7,5.9,15.6-1.9c1.1-7-5.8-5.9-11.7-5.8
    c-6.2-2.7,6.9-1.9,9.7-1.9c5.2,0,10.4,0,15.6,0c0.1,1.9,2.4,1.5,3.9,1.9c-2.9,7.7-2.3-0.4-7.8,0
    C306.2,394.7,298.2,400.6,286.4,395.7z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M173.5,426.9C170,420.6,182,437,173.5,426.9L173.5,426.9z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M241.6,438.5c-4.8-4.1,5.8,2.6,5.8,5.8c2.7,2.3,0.2,0.8-1.9,0
    C244.8,441.8,242.1,441.3,241.6,438.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you have some (ActionScript?) code you've tried so far? If so, paste it into your question, so people will help you along the lines you want.

Comment: Nop what I'm only doing is that is to place a png file into illustrator and vectorizing it.

Comment: Right, but presumably you're looking for a programming solution to obtain your anchor point coordinates from your SVG file? I'd assumed this had something to do with Flash (or AS) since you've tagged it as being a Flash question.

Comment: Yeah, this is going to take some programming.  When I do this stuff, I rely on Processing with the Geomerative library.  In the meantime, I'd read up on how SVG paths work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 1):

How about using an actionscrpt SVG parser like the one from [libspark](http://www.libspark.org/browser/as3/SvgParser/trunk/src), which you can export via: `svn export http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/SvgParser/`

It should be matter of passing the SVG xml to a SVGSprite to render it in flash:

```
var svgSprite: SvgDisplay = new SvgDisplay( svgxml );   //parse SVG
addChild( svgSprite );
```

There are other SVG parsers in as3 : [as3svgrenderlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/) or the [SVG to FIVe3D post](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/converting-svg-to-five3d-flash-vector-graphics-and-html5-canvas/),
but I've used succesfully used libspark SvgParser in the past.